# Volume Rendering in X3D

Tags: x3d

So recently I started working with X3D and have been trying to experiment around with Volume Rendering but I can't seem to get anything working. I have an X3D file with the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE X3D PUBLIC "ISO//Web3D//DTD X3D 3.3//EN" "http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.3.dtd">
<X3D profile='Interchange' version='3.3'  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation =' http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.3.xsd '>
<head>
<component level='1' name='VolumeRendering'/> 
</head> 
<Scene>
<Group>
<Viewpoint DEF='VP' description='Basic Brain' orientation='-0.0212122 0.99986 0.012461 3.23009' position='-0.00920216 0.012033 -0.184913'/> 
<Background DEF='BG' skyColor='1 1 1'/> 
<Transform scale='0.117188 0.117188 0.117188'>
<VolumeData dimensions='1.28 1.28 1.0' containerField='children'>
<ImageTexture3D containerField='voxels' 
  url=' "datasets/nrrd/supine.nrrd"'>
 </ImageTexture3D>
</VolumeData>
</Transform>
</Group>
</Scene>
</X3D>
```

I grabbed this example from the following link and trimmed some of the fat in the head tag. Also, the image that they reference doesn't seem to be on the server so I'm using a different image than the one they use.

http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/Basic/VolumeRendering/BasicBrainIndex.html

Now for some reason when  I open the X3D file and try to view the scene the only thing that seems to render is the background. When I pull it up in BS Content Studio, it gives me an error declaring "Unknown node class 'VolumeData'". As for the X3D player I'm using, I use BS Content Player. Any help would be greatly appreciated because I'm at a bit of a loss right now and haven't received a word back from the BS Content Player support team.

Oh also, I have a folder on my desktop to mirror the url call of datasets/nrrd/supine.nrrd so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Did you check the browser's error console? There might be also some output on X3DOM's console as well. You can activate the latter by pressing D in the scene.

Comment: I just checked the console in the player I'm using and it's giving me the following error: X3D syntax error:  in C:\Users\**\Desktop\volume.x3d:
Unknown node class 'VolumeData'. I replaced the name of my user account with ** for privacy sake.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question that carefully. But apparently you are not using a browser and thus not that you try to use BS Content Player. I'm not familiar with them. But the error suggests already that VolumeData is not implemented within them. You can try to use instant player from instant reality: http://www.instantreality.org/downloads/.

Comment: Thanks a lot mistapink. Upon installing and running the X3D file using the instantplayer like you suggested the NRRD did indeed render as it should have. I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BS Content Player does not support the node `VolumeData`. But you can try to use instant player from instant reality: http://instantreality.org/downloads.

Answer (score 0):

X_ITE works correctly.

https://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/Basic/VolumeRendering/BasicBrainIndex.html

If testing local copy, build.xml file in that directory has target to download (extremely large) datasets.zip holding .nrrd files.